# Python Openssl Sign and Verify functions

Tags: c++, python, c, openssl, x509certificate

I'm currently working on expanding some python code a co-worker wrote to use X509 certificates with the OpenSSL library. I have managed to get all but a few of the OpenSSL functions working. The libraries / functions that I am using are

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import FILETYPE_PEM
from OpenSSL.crypto load_certificate, verify, sign, load_privatekey
```

I am currently creating certificates on my local machine with

```
 openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -out rootcert.pem -outform PEM -days 1825
```

and then "pushing" that to a server (also on local machine), which then returns me a 64 character long random alphanumeric string. I then take the string and sign it using

```
 openssl rsautl -sign -inkey rootprivkey.pem -in string -out signedstring
```

When I push the signed random string to the server, it takes it to verify (using OpenSSL.crypto.verify) with the certificate I previously sent, the process fails. However, if I use the verify function on the command line (`openssl rsautl -verify -inkey rootprivkey.pem -in signedstring`), it works.

If I push the private key to the server and use the OpenSSL.crypto.sign (`sign(private key, data, digest)`) function to sign the same random string and put that into the verify (`verify(certificate, signature, data, digest)`) function, it works.

I've tried all of the different types of padding when signing the string, and none of those worked. I've also tried doing a digest hash of the string first and then signing that file, based on an old question on SO:

```
 openssl dgst -sha1 -binary < string > digeststring
 openssl rsautl -sign -inkey rootprivkey.pem -keyform PEM -in digeststring > signedstring
```

But obviously that did not work either.

I do not know if I am either generating the certificate and signing the string incorrectly, if I am using the OpenSSL.crypto library incorrectly (I have checked many times to make sure that I am passing the correct variables into the OpenSSL functions), or if the command line functions and the python functions are incompatible.

For reference:

```
Python 2.7.3
OpenSSL 1.0.1 (March 12)
```

Comment: What, precisely, is your question? Also, why is this tagged `c++` and `c`? I don't see any reference to either of those languages in the post.

Comment: The question is what the heck am I doing wrong or incorrectly assuming? Why is it that it works only when completely enclosed in one system, but not when I try to move between the two (command line and python)? As for the C / C++ tags, I included those because S.O. suggested they be added and I thought that there might be some relevance with the OpenSSL code. I can remove them if they have no place.